# Unity's Firebase App initializing app error on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, firebase

Using Firebase 1.1.2 with unity 5.4.1

Tried logging an event and I got this message

```
strlen(app_options->app_id()) && strlen(app_options->api_key())
```

Tried search for an issue the only link I found is talking about FCM not sure if it related:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=fr#!topic/firebase-talk/A-Rfls6M__8

Comment: Why not try what's on that page? It says disable stripping when building for Android.

Comment: I have tired , but it not solve my issue.

Comment: Some of these problems are fixed in [Firebase 3](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup). Upgrade to that. If you still have problems after downloading it, check if you have anti-virus. Disable the ant-virus then re-download the [Firebase 3](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup). Test your build before re-enabling the anti-virus.

Comment: Issue solved. My bad for didn't update the firebase to v3.0.0 (didn't see any version indicate on the site so didn't know it was updated).

Thx for point my out

Comment: No problem. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved by update to Firebase 3. Thx @Programmer to point me out.